# Homebrew needs full path?

Tags: php, homebrew

I used to be able to type the following and have it install PHP 5.4:

```
brew install php54
```

Easy peasy. Now when I type this same command I get:

> Error: No available formula for php54

What? Well if instead type:

```
brew install homebrew/php/php54
```

this works. Did more explicit namespacing make it's way into Homebrew recently? Being a sucker for simplicity I would have preferred having a flat namespace and just requiring a uniqueness constraint on naming. Even if we leave convenience aside, something smells off ... for instance, I get into loads of trouble now when I type:

```
brew doctor
```

as it sees my previously installed packages as not having the fully-qualified namespace and spits out tons of output like such:

```
Error: Failed to import: behat
No available formula for behat 
Error: Failed to import: boris
No available formula for boris 
Error: Failed to import: box
No available formula for box 
Error: Failed to import: brew-php-switcher
No available formula for brew-php-switcher 
Error: Failed to import: php52
No available formula for php52 
Error: Failed to import: php53
No available formula for php53 
Error: Failed to import: php53-amqp
No available formula for php53-amqp 
Error: Failed to import: php53-apc
No available formula for php53-apc
```

> **Note:** many files emitted for brevities sake

Also when I type `brew list` I don't get the namespaces:

```
apple-gcc42 dnsmasq     freetype    icu4c       libevent    libpng      libxml2     make        openssl     php54       readline    wget
autoconf    flex        gd      jpeg        libgpg-error    libtiff     libxslt     nginx       pcre        pkg-config  sqlite      zlib
automake    fontconfig  gettext     libcouchbase    libksba     libtool     libyaml     node        phantomjs   re2c        unixodbc
```

Admittedly it's odd to me that the `brew doctor` seemed to mainly be puking over php-related stuff, not all of my packages. Any and all help would be appreciated.

BTW, I am using brew **version 0.9.5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the 'tap' command I was able to get the normal experience back. Specifically you type:

```
 brew tap homebrew/php
```

Then you can do simple installations such as `brew tap php54`. I believe the reason why people may be getting this error is -- and this is just speculation -- that originally the "tap" one used was different. Instead of "homebrew/php" it was "josegonzalez/php" so if you originally installed in the josegonzalez era then you'd likely run into the problem I did.